# How to create a TFRecordReader object using a float_feature in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to both write and read a TFRecord with my data representation as follows:

Input has shape: [100000, 600] and is of type float.

Labels have shape: [100000, 185, 17] and are of type int.

My main question is how to handle the input of type float during the Reading.  I have created the TFRecordWriter as below with no errors (although I am not 100% confident that is correct).  However, I do not know how to decode the resulting raw float feature (I would use tf.decode_raw if it was a string) during the TFRecordReader

**EDIT --- I have figured out how to read the float feature.  It required the use of tf.VarLenFeature which creates a sparse tensor.  The float tensor is then extracted from this by its .values operation.  I have entered the working read_and_decode function below after the error trace.**

```
def convert_to(input, labels, name):
    num_examples = input.shape[0]
    input_dim1 = input.shape[1]
    labels_dim1 = labels.shape[1]
    labels_dim2 = labels.shape[2]
    filename = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, name + '.tfrecords')
    print('Writing', filename)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename)
    for index in range(num_examples):
        input_raw = input[index]
        labels_raw = labels[index].tostring()
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
            'input_d1': _int64_feature(input_dim1),
            'labels_d1': _int64_feature(labels_dim1),
            'labels_d2': _int64_feature(labels_dim2),
            'input_raw': _float_feature(input_raw),
            'labels_raw': _bytes_feature(labels_raw)}))
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
```

Here is the code for the reader that I have attempted that gives me an error when I try and decode the raw input:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
           'input_dim1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
           'labels_dim1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
           'labels_dim2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
           'input_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.float32),
           'labels_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })

   input = features['input_raw']       #CONFUSION HERE
   labels = tf.decode_raw(features['labels_raw'], tf.uint8)

   labels = tf.reshape(labels, [185,17])
   print (labels.shape)                #CORRECTLY GIVES (185, 17)

   input = tf.reshape(input, [600])    #ERROR HERE
   print (input.shape)
```

The error trace is as follows:

File "/users/trabinow/compound_prediction/spectra2smiles/spectra2smiles_refined/spectra2smiles_input.py", line 53, in read_and_decode
    input = tf.reshape(input, [600])

File "/users/trabinow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2630, in reshape
    name=name)

File "/users/trabinow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op op_def=op_def)

File "/users/trabinow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2397, in create_op
    set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)

File "/users/trabinow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1757, in set_shapes_for_outputs
    shapes = shape_func(op)

File "/users/trabinow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1707, in call_with_requiring
    return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)

File "/users/trabinow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
    debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)

File "/users/trabinow/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py", line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
    raise ValueError(err.message)

ValueError: Cannot reshape a tensor with 1 elements to shape [600] (600 elements) for 'tower_0/Reshape_1' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [], [1].

========================================================================

Here is the new working code for the reader:

```
def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
           'input_dim1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
           'labels_dim1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
           'labels_dim2': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
           'input_raw': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
           'labels_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
        })

   input = features['input_raw'].values
   labels = tf.decode_raw(features['labels_raw'], tf.uint8)

   labels = tf.reshape(labels, [185,17])
   print (labels.shape)                #CORRECTLY GIVES (185, 17)

   input = tf.reshape(input, [600])    
   print (input.shape)                 #CORRECTLY GIVES (600,)
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Hmm, what does 'input' look like (in convert_to)?

Comment: type(input) is   <type 'numpy.ndarray'>  -----------
input.shape is   (100000, 600)

Comment: I suspect it's the _float_feature function that's causing this. If you are using something like float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]), this would wrap everything you pass in another list. In this case you would want float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=value) instead.

Comment: I wish that was the solution but I had already fixed that mistake 2 days ago.  My float_feature function has value=value while my int and byte functions have value=[value]